# Faradays Law for a non conducting loop

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

If we consider a non conducting loop moving with a velocity entering a magnetic field, I think it won't be able to induce motional EMF as physically no charge separation is possible in an insulator to generate the EMF. Yet, from the frame of the loop we have a changing magnetic field through the region which must produce an EMF according to Faraday's law. Wouldn't this situation be a contradiction because the EMFs induced are different from different frames due to which Faraday's law will become inapplicable from ground frame as no motional EMF is possible? Does this mean we cannot apply Faraday's law for non conducting materials?

Comment: There is no such thing as a perfect insulator. Dielectrics are polarisable.

Comment: All right so i guess maybe it's just inappropriate to talk about perfect insulators.Thanks!